# ProxyPass with apache to work with node js, framework adonis.js

Tags: node.js, apache, proxypass, adonis.js

I have 4 projects developed in laravel in Apache, now I finish a development in node.js with frmework adonis.js, I want to host that app in Apache as well, since all domain requests enter through port 80 or 443 with ssl, the case is that it creates directories to enter the applications

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName localhost

Alias /app1 /var/www/html/app1/public
Alias /app2 /var/www/html/app2/public
Alias /app3 /var/www/html/app3/public

<Directory /var/www/html/app1/public/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/app2/public/>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/app3/public/>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

the three directories work fine, but those are the 3 project directories in laravel, what should I do to create a 4 directory with the node application js - adonis.js that listens for http: // localhost: 3333 /

Answer (score 0):

You don't need directory for nodejs app. Just start it on any port (I suggest running your app with process manager like [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)) and add proxypass to site config. In your case for port 3333 just add this:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3333/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3333/
```

Of course mod_proxy must be enabled in your apache config.